# Local html page with local file content

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have a bunch of simple plain text files on my machine in which I keep notes about various topics I study or whatever. I decided to make a local html page with some css to serve as quick and simple and css beautified view into these files and use the browser to display them. So I have a page that looks like this.

```
<html>
...
<body>
<ul ...>
<li> <a href="C:/.../Note1.txt">Note1</a> </li>
<li> <a href="C:/.../Note2.txt">Note2</a></li>
...
<li> <a href="C:/.../NoteN.txt">NoteN</a></li>
</ul>
<div name="content_box" ...> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Well obviously clicking on the link will lead me to the text file, but I want it to be displayed with the
css styling so the way I thought I'd solve this issue is by fetching these local files and putting them into this content_box div with an onclick event and disabling the  default events or swaping the  tag for some other tag. The problem is I can't figure out how do I read a local file in native js? I read up on the matter and what I got is having javascript access local files is a security issue and I understand why it's like that, but is there no simple workaround to this problem? Do I have to write some program to convert my note files to webpages if all I want is the plain text content displayed in a stylized box?

Comment: The simple solution to getting around the security issue is to serve your HTML through a simple local web server instead of just going through `file://` URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like this, you'll have to make some changes. As you've said, you can't fetch local files' content from another local file; it would indeed be a security issue.

One possibility would be to put it on a server yourself. Put the files in a static folder on the server, then create a page on the server that can make XMLHttpRequest (or fetch) requests to those files and displays them.

If you don't have a web server, or don't want it to be on the internet, you can install a local one - for example, with [Express](https://expressjs.com/) and a static directory:

```
.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), '/public')))
```

you can then put files into the `public` directory on your file system and they'll be fetchable from your page. You'll be able to navigate to this page with a URL similar to `http://localhost:3000/` (check your Express config to see/change the port).

Answer (score 0):

There's not much styling you can do on a `.txt` file anyway: you can only set the font and the width of the text until it wraps to the next line.

- The font can be changed in your browser settings. Most browsers have a separate font setting for monospace, which gets used here.
- The width can be changed by including the `.txt` file an `<iframe>` of your desired width.

This may not be entirely what you asked for, but the alternative is to create a simple server, which doesn't have to be hard but is certainly a bit more involved.